# CakePHP 3 - unable to generate a query with WHERE...OR conditions

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

CakePHP 3.7

I'm trying to generate a query which uses a `WHERE...OR` pattern. The equivalent in MySQL - which executes and gives the results I want is:

```
SELECT * FROM groups Groups WHERE (regulation_id = 1 AND label like '%labelling%') OR (id IN(89,1,8,232,228,276,268,294));
```

I've read the Advanced Conditions (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions) part of the documentation but can't generate that query.

Assume the Table class is `Groups` I have this:

```
$Groups = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Groups');

$groups_data = $Groups->find('all')->where(['regulation_id' => 1);

$groups_data = $groups_data->where(['label LIKE' => '%labelling%']);
```

This produces the first segment of the `WHERE` statement, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM groups Groups WHERE (regulation_id = 1 AND label like '%labelling%')
```

However I can't see how to attach the `OR` condition, especially since `orWhere()` is deprecated.

So I've tried this - which is even given as an example in the docs:

```
$in_array = [89,1,8,232,228,276,268,294]; // ID's for IN condition

$groups_data = $groups_data->where(['OR' => ['id IN' => $in_array]]);
```

But this just appends an `AND` to the inside of my existing SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM groups Groups WHERE (regulation_id = 1 AND label like '%labelling%' AND id IN(89,1,8,232,228,276,268,294);
```

Which does not yield the correct results as the syntax isn't what's required to run this query.

How do you "move out" of the `WHERE` and append an `OR` condition like in the vanilla query?

I made several attempts using `QueryExpression` as per the docs, but all of these produced PHP Fatal Errors saying something to do with the Table class - I doubt this was on the right lines anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"moving out" is a little tricky, you have to understand that internally the conditions are pushed into a `\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression` object which by default uses `AND` to concatenate the statements, so whatever you push on to that, will be added using `AND`.

When you create `OR` statements, being it implicitly with the shown nested array syntax, or explicitly by using the expression builder, this creates a separate, self-contained expression, where its parts are being concatenated using `OR`, it will compile itself (and since there's only one condition, you don't see any `OR`'s), and the result will be used in the parent expression, which in your case is the main/base expression object for the queries where clause.

Either pass the whole thing at once (being it via array syntax or expressions), eg:

```
$groups_data->where([
    'OR' => [
        'AND' => [
            'regulation_id' => 1,
            'label LIKE' => '%labelling%'
        ],
        'id IN' => $in_array
    ]
]);
```

and of course you could build that array dynamically if required, or, if you for some reason need to use separate calls to `where()`, you could for example overwrite the conditions (third parameter of `where()`), and include the current ones where you need them:

```
$groups_data->where(
    [
        'OR' => [
            $groups_data->clause('where'),
            'id IN' => $in_array
        ]
    ],
    [], 
    true
);
```

Comment: This works and does exactly what I need. But I do think either code is unreadable because if someone cast their eye at that, they'd have no idea that's what SQL it generated. If I do a debug on `$groups_data->sql()` the `AND` condition comes before the `OR` which isn't what it looks like in the array. Still it works though, so I can't argue with that :)

Comment: is there any documentation that explains how to construct these? I need to adapt the query now so it uses `WHERE(... AND ...)  OR (... AND ...)`

Comment: @Andy It actually makes sense, the `AND/OR` operators in the SQL code are the branch nodes in the array/tree structure. So `OR` is the root node in your example, it has two children, both of which are `AND` nodes, of which each have two children themselves.

Comment: @Andy So what you want can be represented as 
`'OR' => [['a' => 1, 'b' => 2], ['a' => 2, 'b' => 1]]`. The `AND` key is optional as it is the default, and because PHP requires array keys to be unique, which would require additional nesting like this: `'OR' => [['AND' => ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2]], ['AND' => ['a' => 2, 'b' => 1]]]`. **https://gist.github.com/ndm2/b8ea970e20ed09abce7b7647a32dee01**

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is old but maybe someone is looking. Here is my solution:

```
protected $_hardValues= array(
    'company_id' => $company_from_session;
);
function beforeFind($event=null, $query = null, $options = null, $primary = true){
    $conds = [];
    $columns = $this->getSchema()->columns();
    foreach( $this->_hardValues as $field => $value){
        if( !is_null($value) && in_array($field, $columns) ){
            $conds[$this->_alias . '.' . $field] = $value;
        }
    }
    if( empty( $conds)) return true;
    $where = $query->clause('where'); //QueryExpression object;
    if( empty( $where)){
        $query->where($conds);
    }else{
        $where->add($conds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of CakePHP 4.x, the documented way of doing this is:

```
$query = $articles->find()
->where([
    'author_id' => 3,
    'OR' => [['view_count' => 2], ['view_count' => 3]],
]);
```

See [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)